# ¿Por qué cuando intento mover el rectángulo en processing se mueve a tirones?

Tags: java

Acabo de empezar con processing y estoy intentando hacer que el rectángulo se mueva a la izquierda presionando la 'A' y a la derecha presionando la 'D', el problema es que escribo el código como veo en tutoriales(http://www.programacionyrobotica.com/interaccion-con-el-teclado-en-processing/)! estoy usando el ejemplo 4 de este enlace al tutorial, en este caso usando la sentencia 'switch' y avanza a tirones, ¿Dónde tengo el error? Estoy utilizando Processing 3.3.7.

```
//Variables
int x = 480;
int y = 520;

void setup() {
  //Se ajusta el tamaño de la ventana
  size(960, 540);
  background(0, 0, 0);
}

void draw() {
  //Dibujo el rectángulo
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(x, y, 80, 10);
  //Movimiento con teclas
  if (keyPressed) {
    switch(keyCode) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    x--;
    break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
    x++;
    break;
    }

    //Limitar trayectoria
    if (x>=520)
      x=520;
    if (x<=20)
      x=20;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Cesar alexis martinez muñoz
int posx=250;

void setup(){
    size(500,500);
}

void draw()
{
    background(255);
    //avion
    fill(170,208,100);

    //enfrente
    noStroke();
    ellipse(posx,325,50,50);
    //alas
    ellipse(posx,350,120,50);
    //cuerpo
    rect(posx-25,325,50,100);
}
}


void keyPressed()
{

    if(keyCode=='D')
    posx=posx+5;

    if(keyCode=='A')
    posx=posx-5;
}
```

Comment: Edita tu respuesta para añadir mas información no agregues otra, por favor terminar el [tour] y lee [answer]

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Tu respuesta debería redactarse en mejor manera. La pregunta del inicio es más indicada para publicarse como comentario de la pregunta y para el resto de la pregunta, te recomendaría que incluyeras referencia a otros sitios en internet donde ayuden a complementar tu respuesta. Te recomiendo que leas este artículo: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tú ejemplo usa la sentencia "if", se que se puede hacer así, pero quiero saber si utilizando "switch" que es como lo estoy haciendo se puede hacer o he cometido algún error en el código. Gracias por responder.